# Redirect existing windows via SSH and X11 forwarding?

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

Using `ssh -X user@host` I can start programs on the host and X11 forwarding allows me to see their windows on the remote machine. However, I'd like to be able to forward/redirect **existing** windows.

How would I do that (if it's possible at all)?

Note, VNC is not an option (no server installed on the host and my user has limited permissions).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like [`xpra`](https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Usage) is an active successor to xmove, and does exactly what you want. The devs bill it as "screen for X clients". While it needs to run on your remote server, it runs just fine out of a home folder. Besides python, `xvfb` is a runtime dependency.

Once you get it installed on the remote server, it's pretty easy to use.

```
xpra start :8 --start=xeyes
```

On your local machine, run:

```
xpra attach ssh:YOURSERVERHOST:8
```

Comment: Bah, `xvfb` isn't installed by default. Anyways, a good answer for people without permission restrictions. Will wait a couple of days and accept if there's no better solution. :)

Comment: Hehe, I know this starts to sound ridiculous, but my xvfb package depends on xserver-common stuff and installs documentation and two executables: `xvfb` and `xvfb-run`. Could be a simple copy to your remote ~/bin..

Comment: For those with permissions to install apps, it appears [xpra](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xpra) has been [in the Universe repositories since Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xpra)

Comment: How does this move existing windows? xpra must be started before xeyes in the example.

Comment: @sivann I interpret "existing" to mean windows created before an ssh session (eg seated at the computer), not before the prereqs for the solution are in place.

Answer (score 1):

I read on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/58018/in-linux-can-i-send-a-running-window-to-a-new-display) that you might be able to do that with `xmove`

Comment: With the caveat that it's no longer developed, and has no official web presence. It is in the 9.x repos I think. Rumour has it has issues (minor? major?) with current X11 releases. I tried to compile it without success, but I don't claim to know much beyond running make.